# bold is not getting applied for labels in J

Tags: css, javafx, fonts, java-8

I have added a custom font in java fx css file. I have labels and text both component. I tried this

```
@font-face {    
    src: url(Helvetica.ttf); 
} 
.text { 
    -fx-font-family: "Helvetica"; 
    -fx-font-smoothing-type: gray; 
},
```

It is working fine for text,But if i try

```
.label{ 
    -fx-font-family: "Helvetica" ; 
    -fx-font-smoothing-type: gray;
}
```

The font is getting changed, But only regular font is coming

```
.D_17_BOLD_FONT {    
 -fx-font-size: 17px;     
-fx-font-weight: bold;     
-fx-text-fill: white; 
}
```

With this font size is getting changed, Bold is not applied (only regular font is coming).

Comment: The bold version of the font recides in a different font file...

Comment: label{ 
    -fx-font-family: "Helvetica-Bold" ; 
    -fx-font-smoothing-type: gray;
} i have added this but in usr/share/font/truetype ,suppose if i have helvetica.ttf, helvietica-bold.ttf ,   It is taking only one font. if i delete helvetica.ttf it is taking helvetica-Bold.ttf. I need both.

Answer (score 0):

instead of what you've done try:

```
-fx-font-weight: bold;
```

for the label's css (Always works)